# Looking for an easier way to parse a timestamp in Python

Tags: python, date

I am gathering data from an API that returns a timestamp in the following format: 'Thu May 22 15:40:24 +0000 2014', however, I need to convert it into a YYYY-MM-DD for my database. I wrote a function to do this, but it is quite ugly and I am wondering if someone tried to do this with some Python standard library module, e.g., `datetime`?

```
time = 'Thu May 22 15:40:24 +0000 2014'

def simplify_date(timestamp):
    """ 
    Converts a timestamp of the format
    'Thu May 22 15:40:24 +0000 2014' into a
    date string YYYY-MM-DD, e.g., '2014-05-22'.

    """
    months = {'Jan':'01', 'Feb':'02', 'Mar':'03',
              'Apr':'04', 'May':'05', 'Jun':'06',
              'Jul':'07', 'Aug':'08', 'Sep':'09',
              'Oct':'10', 'Nov':'11', 'Dec':'12'
              }
    t = timestamp.split()
    date = '%s-%s-%s' %(t[-1], months[t[1]], t[2])
    return date

print(simplify_date(time))
2014-05-22
```

Comment: why dont you use the datetime strftime function

Comment: Have you looked into [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime)?

Comment: sorry, yes i mean `strptime`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can potentially use the [`datetime.datetime.strptime`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-behavior) function to get a `datetime` object which can then be formatted via `strftime` to any format you want.

```
>>> ts = "Thu May 22 15:40:24 +0000 2014"
>>> dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(ts, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")
>>> dt.strftime("%Y-%m-%d")
'2014-05-22'
```

However, there is a caveat that `strptime` doesn't handle timezone offsets well in Python 2. As long as the timezone is constant (`+0000`) you can just hard-code that into your format string. If you're using Python 3, you can use `%z` instead to match timezone offsets, but in Python 2 that won't work.

Also note that I've used `%b` above for the month - that matches on the *short* versions of month names. If the API actually returns the long version (hard to tell, since you used the one month that's never abbreviated in your example), you'll need `%B` instead.

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I believe that is correct (OP did not specify Python version, though). Edited slightly to clarify when it's useful.

Comment: Thanks, that was something I was looking for :)

Answer (score 1):

you can do something like this

```
import datetime

time = 'Thu May 22 15:40:24 +0000 2014'

new_time = datetime.datetime.strptime(time, "%a %b %d %H:%M:%S +0000 %Y")

print new_time.strftime("%Y-%d-%m")
```

[Python Doc.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html)

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for the time.strftime function. You can find more information about this in  [the python documentation on strftime.](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html#time.strftime)